# Rails Chartkick - How to compare with string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

Currently learning how to use rails/ruby and wanted to do some graphing using Chartkick. Following some tutorial I seeded the follow dummy data

```
Visit.delete_all
Visit.create  country: 'United States', visited_at: DateTime.now, load_time: 3.5
Visit.create  country: 'United States', visited_at: DateTime.now, load_time: 1.5
Visit.create  country: 'United States', visited_at: DateTime.now, load_time: 1.0
Visit.create  country: 'United States', visited_at: DateTime.now - 1.day, load_time: 4.5
Visit.create  country: 'United States', visited_at: DateTime.now - 1.day, load_time: 4.0
Visit.create  country: 'United States', visited_at: DateTime.now - 2.days, load_time: 3.5
Visit.create  country: 'United States', visited_at: DateTime.now - 2.days, load_time: 1.0
Visit.create  country: 'United States', visited_at: DateTime.now - 2.days, load_time: 3.5
Visit.create  country: 'United States', visited_at: DateTime.now - 3.days, load_time: 4.5
Visit.create  country: 'United States', visited_at: DateTime.now - 3.days, load_time: 3.0
Visit.create  country: 'Germany', visited_at: DateTime.now, load_time: 1.0
Visit.create  country: 'Germany', visited_at: DateTime.now, load_time: 2.0
Visit.create  country: 'Germany', visited_at: DateTime.now, load_time: 1.0
Visit.create  country: 'Germany', visited_at: DateTime.now, load_time: 3.0
Visit.create  country: 'Germany', visited_at: DateTime.now - 1.day, load_time: 4.0
Visit.create  country: 'Germany', visited_at: DateTime.now - 2.days, load_time: 2.0
Visit.create  country: 'Germany', visited_at: DateTime.now - 2.days, load_time: 1.0
Visit.create  country: 'Germany', visited_at: DateTime.now - 2.days, load_time: 3.0
Visit.create  country: 'Germany', visited_at: DateTime.now - 3.days, load_time: 3.5
Visit.create  country: 'South Korea', visited_at: DateTime.now, load_time: 2.0
Visit.create  country: 'South Korea', visited_at: DateTime.now, load_time: 2.5
Visit.create  country: 'South Korea', visited_at: DateTime.now, load_time: 1.0
Visit.create  country: 'South Korea', visited_at: DateTime.now, load_time: 1.5
Visit.create  country: 'South Korea', visited_at: DateTime.now - 1.day, load_time: 2.5
Visit.create  country: 'South Korea', visited_at: DateTime.now - 1.day, load_time: 4.0
Visit.create  country: 'South Korea', visited_at: DateTime.now - 1.day, load_time: 3.0
Visit.create  country: 'South Korea', visited_at: DateTime.now - 2.days, load_time: 1.0
Visit.create  country: 'South Korea', visited_at: DateTime.now - 3.days, load_time: 5.0
Visit.create  country: 'South Korea', visited_at: DateTime.now - 3.days, load_time: 4.0
Visit.create  country: 'South Korea', visited_at: DateTime.now - 3.days, load_time: 5.0
```

I'm trying to plot a line graph where I can generate one div(graph) per unique country with the visit count grouped by date using the following code

```
  <% Visit.pluck("country").uniq.each do |input| %>    
  <div class = "GraphDiv">
    Country: <%= input %><br/>
    <%= line_chart @visits.group(:country => input).group_by_day(:visited_at, format: "%B %d, %Y").count, discrete: true, height: "300px",
                   :library => {
                           backgroundColor: "transparent",
                           vAxis: {textStyle: { color: 'black'} },
                           hAxis: { textStyle: { color: 'black'} }
                   } %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

but I'm having trouble with the query. I've tried using where, group, and other condition but it always throw some syntax error. How do I compare with "input"?

Comment: Maybe it helps to know that you can play around with your query with `rails c`? Also to me it looks as if you want to do `@visits.where(country: input)`.

Comment: `group_by_day` is not available with `ActiveRecord::Relation`, so you may be getting `undefined method group_by_day`for  `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Please double check

Comment: @visits.where(country: input) gives unsupported: Hash error. I'm not sure if I've explained clearly what I'm trying to do. Input is suppose to be country name and since theres repeated entry of the same country , I used. uniq, it seems to work since it was able to produce 3 different div with uniq country name.

I want to be able to filter out result and plot only for that specific country for a particular div corresponding to the heading (input). But I'm struggling with query as I've never worked with database before.

Comment: what is the statement for `@visits`, where its populating?

Comment: nvm, thanks for helping guys, solved it by replacing group with where. not sure why it didn't work the first time around